# Is reusing old code for a new assignment considered self plagiarism? How to protect yourself if you consider it to be, and a group partner does not?

Tags: ethics, self-plagiarism, cheating, group-dynamics

I am taking a graduate machine learning course and am working with another student in the class on a final project. In his undergraduate studies, the other student wrote code that accomplished a similar task, and mentioned in our previous meeting that we would be able to leverage much of this code for our current project if we wanted to. I responded that I believe it would constitute textbook cheating and self-plagiarism, but the other student disagrees and believes that re-using the code would not constitute self-plagiarism because he himself wrote it, and it would be redundant to re-write what he had already done.

Now, the course instructors have made it clear that we are not allowed to use any external libraries to perform certain classes of algorithms for this project. This students' prior code would fall under this category of prohibited tools, but he claims that it doesn't qualify because he wrote the code himself (so it is not an "external library"). I believe this is hyperbole, but he disagrees. It is also worth mentioning that this code is licensed under an [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License), though it is not widely used at all.

It has gotten to the point where I am uncomfortable going forward with the project by re-using his old code, and he does not want to do work on the project that he considers to be redundant. My worry is that if it turns out we're not allowed to reuse the code, then using it could cause us to fail the course and severely negatively affect our reputations. Even if we don't get caught, I personally feel that it would be unethical to copy-paste old code and present it as though it's fresh code for this current project.

I am unsure of how to proceed. I have tried reaching out to the professor of the course some time ago (she has been traveling for some conferences recently and will be for a while) but I have not heard back from her. Additionally, the course TAs have been unwilling to weigh-in on the situation.

I have the following questions:

1. Is the above situation usually considered to be self plagiarism? Why or why not?
2. Is the above act typically allowed in an academic setting?
3. Assuming you are in my position, and consider re-using the code to be cheating and/or unethical, what is the best way to proceed; both in terms of how to make progress on the project, how to compromise with my group mate, and how to protect myself if my group mate refuses to budge.

Comment: If people voting down the question could explain why, that would be helpful. It seems that I'm misunderstanding the concept of self plagiarism, and if someone could explain why I would appreciate it.

Comment: Among other reasons, you've made this *very strongly* moralistic for something that's at best an edge case.

Comment: Again, if that's the case, please define self plagiarism. I don't see how this doesn't fit the definition to a T.

Comment: Part of the problem is that self-plagarism is somewhat ill-definined, especially for something like code. That's part of the problem - you've drawn some very sharp lines and started throwing around some very moralistic language around something that's at best ill-defined.

Comment: I'm drawing sharp lines around a sharp topic. If it is cheating (which other students I've asked have agreed that it is), then how else should I handle it? Morals are often a gray area, but they're dealt with severely. That's why people come on message boards and ask for other peoples' opinions on them.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable working with someone because, in your judgement, they are dong something unethical that may entangle you, then **stop working with them.**

Comment: If your classmate says the truth, whatever you do, he will be inspired by this written code. As it is his knowledge, he can use this knowledge. Maybe, not taking the written code entirely same but some parts of it. In the field of theoretical economics, people use their written code for many papers. Is it self-plagiarism ? 
By the way, if it is really his code, you can not find it on a library or somewhere else. So, is it really a self-plagiarism ? Also, I don't fnd correct your pre-judgement about your classmate. 
To be secure, the best is to talk with your professor.

Comment: Your understanding of self-plagiarism aside, your assertion that it is unethical in *all* cases is simply unjustified. Just because you have named a concept doesn't mean you have correctly judged the morality of that concept. It would be great if there were a name for this all-too-common logical fallacy, but ironically quoting a name for it as a substitute for explaining why it is a fallacy would be an example of itself.

Comment: I appreciate the people on this thread who actually gave me advice for how to proceed; which namely was to send an inquiry to the professor, wait to hear back, and do other work on the project as we can in the meantime. As I mentioned in the question, I emailed her some time  ago and only just heard back. She stated that if we were to reuse his code that it would be considered cheating and we would fail the course.

Comment: From my eyes, though it's obvious that many of you will strongly disagree, the lesson to be learned here is that you *should* treat "edge case" issues of academic integrity seriously. Err on the side of caution. There is no reason to assume that everyone has the same idea as you of what constitutes cheating, self-plagiarism, whatever. Many of the responses were, "I don't consider that cheating, so it's not cheating." Realistically, "cheating" is whatever the professor judges it to be. Thanks again to the people who offered relevant answers to my questions.

Comment: I think you are getting answers that aren't what you were looking for because the way the question is phrased is not really accurate. A "classmate who refuses to acknowledge self plagiarism" would be one who wants to hide the fact that the code is reused, or who insists on using it even after you hear back from the instructor that it's not allowed. What you have *here* is a classmate that disagrees on the interpretation of the rules of the course, which is a completely different question. I think an [edit] to the post is in order.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit While I fully agree that the OP is overly moralistic about the point, you can [in fact plagiarise yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism#Self-plagiarism), although admittedly it doesn't really apply to OP's case.

Comment: I would also suggest that in the context of more complex code, even if your colleague won't use previous code explicitly he would instinctively be inclined to implement conceptually similar solutions. In effect, to be consistent with your desire your teammate would have to strive to develop purposely different solution. The fact is that in analytical and software development environment, especially while working under pressure, you will be inclined to re-use concepts that you know. Even if your colleague won't look at the code, the experience will influence his approach to the problem.

Comment: @ff524 I have edited the question. Do you feel that it is more accurate and clear? If not, please feel free to edit it further.

Comment: You've mentioned in other comments on answers that you are not interested in answers to the question "Is reusing old code for a new assignment considered self plagiarism?" - have you changed your mind on that?

Comment: @ff524 I have, given that my opinion on the topic was clearly quite biased and it seems relevant to how I should proceed with my project partner.

Comment: Then yes, this title seems much more accurate to me. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I just read the changes to the body of the post. "Do you consider this to be..." and "Should this be..." both seem too opinion-based to me (see the [help/dont-ask].) Given that this question has already attracted a few close votes, I suggest changing this to ask what the convention is ("Is this usually considered...") rather than what people's opinions are.

Comment: I have further edited the question

Comment: I think I've just witnessed my first case of "sealioning" - http://wondermark.com/1k62/

Comment: Oops. I once used the code segment `i++;` in one of my older projects. Now I'm not allowed to use that code segment ever again!

Comment: For our Language & Compilers 2 course the professor **expects** you to reuse the code you have written for LC1. Given that you have to write a complete front end (up to intermediate code generation) from scratch in like 180 hours (note: straight hours, i.e. 180/24=7,5 days of continuous work. Sleeping time is counted towards the hours used). If you already have the parser and typechecker ready you can manage to add the code generation part in that time, rewriting everything is simply impossible.

Comment: I don't think plagiarism is particularly relevant here. This is just about marking. What is your University's policy on previously marked code? I recently completed an MSc, in which it was explicitly stated that being marked for the same code more than once was not allowed. However, that's not to say that you couldn't build upon previous code (noting which code was taken from elsewhere), and get marks for the new work.

Comment: I can understand why you'd ask this question - self-plagiarism is a difficult problem to define.  However, in CS, re-using old code is generally accepted, encouraged even, when it would be useful, and as long as you reference the fact that old code that you *know* works is being used, I don't see a problem.  You should still definitely run it by the professor, but if you go through the effort to make sure the old code works in the new setting, I wouldn't see any problem with that, and I'd hope your professor wouldn't either.

Comment: I would like to add why your self-plagiarism definition is not really applicable, especially to code. In CS, papers are often based on some program/library and subsequent performance measurements. So lets assume an author would code such a program and publish a paper based on it. If he/she decides to use the code again and extend it and publish a new paper about it, that would be totally fine (and no one would expect the author to recode the same stuff again). However, it would be self-plagiarism if the pictures or paragraphs would simply be copy-pasted for the new publication

Comment: Gotta agree with Lightness here.  "Self-plagiarism" is a silly term, bringing to mind an act exactly as heinous as "robbing your own house."

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Well if that house is leased to someone else.

Comment: OK, while it's debatable whether this constitutes plagarism at all, you can cover yourselves entirely (in terms of ethics) by clearly and unambiguously stating that you are using this code and showing clearly what parts are from it. At that point you are 100% no longer committing plagiarism, self or otherwise,  and there is no *ethical* or *honor* problem with it. The professor may choose to *withhold or deduct marks* for re-used code but as long as you are clear, open and honest about sources it cannot be plagiarism(disciplinary offense).  (MIT license bit is utterly irrelevant )

Answer (score 100, accepted):

What should you do?  You should ask the professor politely and without imposing your pre-judgement on whether this is or is not prohibited by the rules of the class.  You are not in a position to make this judgement.  The only person who can give a definitive ruling is the professor who set the rules.

I recommend an approach like:

> My teammate has previously created code that would be very applicable to this project.  Can we use that code, or does it count as an external library, and we should instead write it again as an exercise?

While you are waiting for a response, I would recommend proceeding in two ways in parallel:

1. You implement a new version of the library from scratch, while
2. Your partner builds upon the existing library.

That way, you get the educational value of building the library, rather than using the pre-existing library, and your partner can push on ahead without either of you being stalled while waiting for the result.

Comment: I think suggesting to rewrite it is a bit silly. First off, whats the stop a giant ctrl-a, ctrl-c? If my goal is to rewrite something I've written before, I'd hardly call that plagiarism. Second, whats the benefit of actually rewriting it? Just so you can check some mental checkbox?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg The answer suggest that the OP rewrites the code, not his colleague who originally wrote the library. That's reproducing someone else's results and in most cases a good learning experience.

Comment: Additionally, the OP might come upon optimizations while rebuilding the library so regardless of whether or not it's plagiarism it's still going to have an educational value

Comment: Since the other student published his work, you'll definitely want to discuss it with the professor.  Even if you did convince him to rewrite it from scratch, odds are it would be similar enough to trigger any anti-plagiarism tools the professor uses.

Comment: The process of *refactoring it out* into its own library would almost certainly be beneficial in many ways -- and a great opportunity to improve the code itself and take another look at what it does and understand what the point of it is. By that point, it is no longer self plagiarism by any measure, imo. This is totally different from copypasting code all over the new project.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Professional programmer chiming in: Re-writing your own code is a great exercise. You can always make it more elegant, more flexible, faster, better, even if you don't rewrite it in a new language or framework. Any talented programmer could rewrite his treasured libraries over and over again if not constrained by time and reason. In moderation, it's a great way to become a better programmer.

Comment: +1 Asking the professor is an answer to OP's first, realistic question, and if the prof allows the copying, then OP's second question (in the title) is invalid. If the prof doesn't allow the copying, then the answer to OP's second question is simply "Tell your teammate not to use the old code, since the prof says so."

Comment: @DavidsaysReinstateMonica There is a benefit. A great deal of code written can stand to be improved. It's a mindset that a developer should have, that just as work that was written before can be reused, it can also stand to be improved and expanded upon. That the teammate wants to slap it in as-is carries a bit of hubris that I see as a negative personality trait of complacency. I couldn't expect well-maintained code from someone like that.

Answer (score 74):

Like qsp, I'm not of the opinion that this is self-plagarism.

Nor do I think it's an 'external library' by any meaningful sense of the word. For that matter, what are you expecting him to really do - he's already written code to do this, even if he wrote it again from scratch, is he not allowed to refer to other things he's done? I *constantly* look back at old code (I did this in a clever way sometime last year...). Where do you draw the line - are you allowed to look back at *your* old code if you can't remember something basic, but know you've done it before?

If you want to make the argument that *you* won't learn anything if it's already done and implemented, I could understand that. The problem is that you've dug in your heels on making this an ethical issue when that's at best questionable, and to be frank, if you used the language you've used about your partner with me, you'd likely poison our working relationship as well.

Comment: There is a very fine line between referencing your old work, and copying and pasting half of a previous project. People forget things over time, and if he already knows the material I don't think it's unreasonable at all to expect him to reimplement it. This isn't the private industry, this is a graduate program where everybody has to follow the same policies.

Comment: @110100101110101 Based on your commenting and voting, I'm not sure you're not just fishing for someone to agree with you.

Comment: Also, I don't see how using language such as "cheating" and "unethical behavior" is in poor taste if it is an edge case. Are you saying people should throw caution to the wind? I've attended institutions where students failed courses for this *exact* reason. Literally because they copied and pasted code.

Comment: Nobody has answered my question, they've only said, "it's not cheating". You don't know the policies at my institution, nor do you know the specifics of my situation. If you update your answer to answer my question, I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: I'm saying *it's not clear it's cheating*. If a student came to me and said "I've already written the code that does large parts of X, can I just use that?" the answer would be yes. You can't get the TAs to answer, and the Prof. hasn't weighed in. The only authority declaring it's cheating is you. You asked us, and several people said "We don't really think it's cheating." That is an answer...it's just not one you like.

Comment: I understand that, but again, that doesn't answer the question of how to handle it if it *is* cheating. That was my question. Assume it's plagiarism. How do you protect yourself? All you said was, "you're poisoning your relationship with your peer". Frankly, that is not helpful. Also, nobody has said, "We don't really think it's cheating." That's the point. None of the instructors have weighed in.

Comment: @110100101110101 This question (which differs from what you actually asked imho) would be closed on this site, because it is theoretically. Your assumption that it is plagiarism is seen as invalid by almost everyone here, so in short I would say your assumption is incorrect. Every reasoning based on an incorrect assumption is purely theoretical and of no value and will also be incorrect, so what is the point in answering it? Even if you don't accept the predominant opinion here, please acknowledge it at least that we reject your assumption.

Comment: In University, I regularly re-use code from previous projects (either other class projects or code I've written at work and have permission to use from my employer). There is nothing to gain from re-writing exactly something you have already solved - and it's great practice for real-world development where this sort of thing is expected and commonplace.

Answer (score 43):

Your question raises interesting issues of honesty, teamwork and psychology. Let's examine how some of those ideas interact in your situation.

> Now, the course instructors have made it clear that we are not allowed
>   to use any external libraries to perform certain classes of algorithms
>   for this project. This students' prior code would fall under this
>   category of prohibited tools, but he claims that it doesn't qualify
>   because he wrote the code himself (so it is not an "external
>   library"). I believe this is hyperbole, but he staunchly disagrees.

Okay, so you and your partner disagree about something; this is not an infrequent occurrence during a collaboration. However, it seems to me that you are approaching this debate from a point of view that assumes that there is some objective truth here, and furthermore feel very strongly that that truth is on your side: your partner's old code logically seems to you to be an external library, and you are having a hard time believing that anyone could honestly think otherwise, unless he is motivated by laziness or self-interest. Well, actually I think that's far from the case; not only is it not obvious to me and to some of the other users here whether old code will count as "external library" or whether reusing it counts as self-plagiarism, but I think even the course professor might not be sure and have to think a bit when asked this question (and I say this as a professor who has some experience being asked unusual questions that I did not expect by my students in connection to my course policies). So, a first piece of advice I would give you is to tone down your rhetoric a bit. Yes, *maybe* reusing old code is a bad idea and will be seen as dishonest, especially if done without acknowledging it. You are quite reasonable in being concerned about this and worrying about your reputation. You should certainly check this, but before you start throwing around words like "hyperbole", it's a good idea to be a little bit more humble, make fewer assumptions and be more open to the possibility that other very reasonable people may disagree with you about this.

> It has gotten to the point where the other student and I cannot see
>   eye to eye on this issue, and I am worried that if he refuses to
>   simply accept that we have to do all the work for this project [...]

I think you need to remember that your partner is a **member of your team**. You are not his boss and cannot demand that he do things exactly the way you want or accept your way of thinking. Furthermore, this project is not just an exercise in programming, it is also meant to teach you teamwork -- the art of working as a team, which is something that's highly valued by employers, in some cases much more than specific programming or machine learning wizardry. When you talk about him "refusing to simply accept that we have to [do things my way]", and say that you have reached a point where you and your partner are close to being completely unable to work with each other, I see this as a failure to establish effective teamwork. Disagreements will come up in any collaborative project; you are now being tested on your ability to work through them effectively, by *talking* to your team member, and also by *listening* to him and being open to hearing and accepting his point of view.

> Nobody has answered my question, they've only said, "it's not
>   cheating". [...] that doesn't answer the question of how to handle it
>   if it *is* cheating. That was my question. Assume it's plagiarism. 
>   How do you protect yourself?

Well, if all you want is an answer to your literal question and don't care to hear any additional analysis: if I had a project partner who was a cheater and I couldn't convince him not to cheat, I would not partner with him. I would go to my professor and ask to be partnered with someone else, or to be given a solo project if that's the only practical option, and explain that working with the current partner is ethically untenable for me.

However, if you *are* willing to consider additional analysis, I will venture to offer my opinion that you are asking the wrong question. Based on my understanding of your situation, I think you are too sure that you are in the right and your partner is in the wrong, and in this case, refusing to partner with him will reflect poorly on you, since it will indicate that you do not have good teamwork skills, which is part of what this project is meant to test and help you develop.

To summarize, the core of your question is actually about a simple matter of how to interpret a course policy that forbids the use of external libraries in a programming project. When professors write their course policies they don't always think of all possible scenarios that could arise, so it is not uncommon for ambiguities to exist. When this happens, the best thing to do is simply to ask the professor (but please ask politely and in a neutral way that does not assume what the correct answer is), then follow their instructions. If you do this, I don't see how your reputation can be hurt.

Answer (score 40):

I'm afraid you are understanding "self-plagiarism" incorrectly. The purpose of coursework project is to help students understand the algorithms. That's why the professor does not allow the use of external libraries.
However, in your case, your partner did implement the task by himself (if his partner in undergraduate did that, it is a different story). So he does not cheat here.

Actually, for this project it is better for you to take the responsibility of doing the task that your partner have done. Because he already fully understood the task, and you don't.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I have misunderstood self-plagiarism, perhaps you could define it in your answer? It seems to me that you're claiming that because the purpose of a course is to teach, that reusing his existing code would not fit the definition of self-plagiarism. In addition, perhaps we come from different academic backgrounds, but I have never attended an institution where students were allowed to reuse their work from previous semesters. If anything, it is typically expressly forbidden.

Comment: @110100101110101 Is he *reusing* his code without *any* modification, or is he simply choosing not to rewrite the wheel? Because I've been to many classes that absolutely do assume you'll build off things you learned before.

Comment: Should a student be allowed to hand in the exact same essay for multiple courses if the general topic is the same? That is the very definition of self-plagiarism. I don't see how the goal of the course to teach the algorithms would change that.

Comment: @Fomite he wants to copy and paste more than half the codebase

Comment: @110100101110101 So when you're accusing him, you use language like 'Should a student be allowed to hand in the exact same essay', but he's only reusing 'more than half'...

Comment: @Fomite, okay I'll rephrase, should a student be allowed to copy and paste half of an essay and hand it in as though it's an original piece of work?

Comment: Talking about 'an essay' is entirely misleading. Re-using code you happen to have written before which proves useful for a new project is certainly different; whether that is acceptable or not depends on class guidelines (but my guess is that yes). Just saying.

Comment: @110100101110101, I would say that the purpose of a class is that the students learn the material. If the student in this case used this algorithm in a previous class then they obviously have learnt the material. The only important question for an assignment should be "Is this project solely the work of the students?". In this case, the answer is "yes".

Comment: @110100101110101 If you're forbidden to reuse previous work in a computer science course, that's just one more way in which academia is completely out of touch with reality.  Students should be *required* to reuse previous work.  How to reuse code effectively should be a major part of the curriculum.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I both agree and disagree. In the real world, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Students should absolutely be instructed that using previous and open existing code for implementations is a GOOD thing. However, if the point is to prove that the student has command of the theory sufficient enough to design a new implementation, then I think it's valid to request brand-new code. If the professor is sensible enough, he may allow the code, but give a better grade for "improving upon and redesigning the logic" so that it is made new from old.

Answer (score 25):

Regarding the rules made by the professor, the letter of the law is clear insofar that it absolutely allows both your interpretation and that of your colleague. So disregard it and look for **intent**.

In terms of intent, what we can do is make an educated guess, but a much easier way to find out about intent is to simply ask the one who made the rule.

Answer (score 21):

In formal academic writing, the problem of self-plagiarism is answered by citing the sources that were used, even if the sources are by the same author.  I think it would not be unethical to reuse the code earlier written by your groupmate as long as your groupmate explicitly states to your professor that the code was written by the groupmate for an earlier course.  Ask your professor if this arrangement is acceptable and does not violate school policy.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see what the problem is. If you have written code before to neatly display certain data, or ask for input from the user, it is silly to not re-use this code. Just make sure to add a comment above the functions or code blocks that have been re-used and briefly list that you are the author, and where you have used it before.

If the course itself is for learning about algorithms, it is unwise to re-use any code that had to do with algorithms. First of all, it is likely not tailored to the problem at hand. Second of all, you do not learn much with copy-pasting. If you have completed the course before, the professor would likely have given you permission to skip the practical assignment. If the professor did not do this, it is likely they want you to redo at least that part.

That said, re-using (part of) the code for tree-building and tree-traversal when you need to implement a search algorithm is fine as far as I am concerned. Trees are not that difficult to implement, but it is boring to have to write that code again and might introduce bugs you already have solved before. You are likely studying computer science and aren't trying to get a degree in Typist Science. Solving problems you have already solved before is not productive. Spend that energy on understanding and implementing the new stuff. If you have done a lot of the project before, just spend time on polishing the project, or ask for a more challenging project. Again, just make sure that there can not be a misunderstanding about where code comes from by puting a comment with author, source location and possible license above the code that has been re-used.

---

Thas said, I think you should learn two things from this:

- Make sure that you and your partner are on the same page at the beginning of the project. It sounds like you might have put off working on the project until it was too late to back out.
- If there are unbridgeable differences between you and your partner, you still have an obligation to finish the project before the deadline. Don't sit around argueing with each other, but work on the project on your own and encourage the partner to do the same. If the differences are not bridgeable in the future, you might need to hand in the project alone. Make sure you make clear which part you did with your former partner, and which part you did alone.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go for a more  succinct answer.

> Is the above situation usually considered to be self plagiarism? Why or why not?

**No**, because: 1. It's not a publication, nobody can plagiarize anything. 2. You're not pretending to have come up with original research results in this assignment.

> Is the above act typically allowed in an academic setting?

**Yes** in my experience (as a student and TA). Really, we don't care about this kind of stuff. Projects and homework are a courtesy to you students, to help you reach a better understanding of the material; and grades are just a rough statistical mechanism.

> Assuming you are in my position... what is the best way to proceed... ?

**You should "cheat"** in this situation. Even if it "doesn't feel right" to you - objectively it's not cheating, and it *is* acceptable to about everyone else concerned.

Comment: To the nay-sayers: Well, _somebody_ has to tell him that :-)

Comment: _Everybody's answers are great, but long._ And I see you decided to take the opposite approach on both counts.

Comment: *You should "cheat". Even if it "doesn't feel right"*. Regardless of what "about everyone else concerned" thinks (I'm impressed that you're a mind reader and can read everyone else's thoughts), that is terrible advice.

Comment: well i up-arrowed this.  still left at -2.

Comment: @DanRomik: Rephrased that sentence to make it less, shall we say, dismissive. More constructive criticism would be appreciated though.

Comment: @110100101110101: The fact that you think this is "terrible advice" is more the problem you're facing than anything else. The "terribleness" is, with all due respect, an incorrect impression of yours. As for reading minds - I don't, I'm extrapolating based on my experience and what you've described. Also note I said "about everyone"...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the problem this way:  Each class you take, is like you being a contractor for that class, writing code for the "company" that is running that class.  So, when you finish the semester, and move on to the next gig (i.e. the new semester starts and you're now in this project), the problem you have here is that, in principle, your partner *does not own that code.*  It's not strictly true, but it's essentially the same type of issue!

You can bring concepts from place to place, but you can't carry CODE from place to place, and that's the same in academia (apparently so in this circumstance, anyway!).  The definitive answer is that you and your partner have to take what is called a "green-field" approach to the code he wants to carry forward...you have to re-write it anew.

Also, the so-called problem of self-plagiarizing is very real and a very common problem.  You can't just pick up academic work done for one class and re-submit it for another class...if you're caught, it's usually a big problem.  You can get by it by going FULL DISCLOSURE, and full citation (to yourself as the previous author) but that's something that requires direct and prescribed intervention BEFORE you hand it in, with the professor involved.  Some will be ok with it, some decidedly not.  It's their call.

My suggestion?  You propose along with your partner that you re-implement his existing API with new code.  You bring the code to the instructor, say that it is what you intend, and get her prior blessing.

Comment: I kindof disagree here. There are several reasons to take a course, to learn and to certificate (get credits). Sometimes you simply have students who know the material but are for reasons beyond them needing the credits. It is perfectly fine for them to leverage on previous knowlege. In a perfect world they would just be given the credit for the work they have done. Unfortunately that seldom happens so they must do this. Also even if the student would rewrite the code he can really never escape having done it before.

Comment: I'm currently in the process of rewriting some VERY SOLID code I wrote previously.  It's amazing how "awful" that previous code is, after a bit of time and some fresh perspective!   Suffice to say, yes, there are only so many algorithms, and only so many ways to skin a cat.  If you've written something before, and now you have to do it again, it's going to come out similarly.  No question about it.  But also suffice to say, there are very valid reasons to have to rewrite!

Comment: I dont claim that repetition dont make better. Its just that it is somewhat wrong to ask a person to redo work when others arent redoing it. People can have other priorities. They are there to learn up to certain standard. Beyond that its the students own initiative. The scool can not demand this, your not evaluating the student by their full potential just the relative level compared to others and some goal level.

Comment: This answer is based on a false premise. Depending on what contracts are in place, *you very well may be able to take your code from place to place*.

Comment: @RubberDuck, after many years of working in the software industry, I have found it to be the case exactly zero times, that code I've written for my employer is freely available to me after I've left.  Except, of course, code that was released as GPL code to the public.  Regardless, it's not germane to the question, which is, "what is the professor's desire here?"

Comment: @dwoz you've neglected the case where you're working on contract to write some program for someone. If the contract is written "correctly", then you *may* retain the right to repackage, redistribute, reuse that code. Obviously, if you're *employed* by someone, a sane legal department will make sure that they own all intellectual property created while we're on the job.